Is it possible to plan Drools rule execution with OptaPlanner/Timefold?
I am working on a project where we use a repository of Drools rules to transform a graph towards a goal graph. The conclusion of a rule represents fixed graph fragments that are added/removed if the rules´ preconditions are met, which means that the applicability of a rule depends on the current state of the graph. Currently, we use hill climbing implemented as additional Drools rules to find the optimal sequence (local optimum) in which rules should be applied in order to approximate our goal state as closely as possible.
Since Timefold was once associated with Drools and this task can be considered a classical planning problem, I was wondering whether Timefold could be put to use here. More precisely, I would need Timefold to find the global maximum (chain of rules) via advanced searching techniques that are available, such as simulated annealing for instance.
From what I have found so far, our best bet would be transforming the rules back to POJOs so that Timefold can process them accordingly. However, this solution seems not quite elegant, as one major reason for our choice of using DRL format was the aspect of them being easily readable for humans. This is why I was wondering whether someone has had a similar experience of integrating Drools into Timefold or some ideas how we could approach this task. I´m grateful for every hint!

Maybe EasyScoreCalculator or IncrementalScoreCalculator provide an extension point to do this. But it's definitely an exotic (and interesting) use case.

Thanks for the tip, I´ll have a look into it.
